# Spring Security Hibernate load user with lazy associations

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-security, lazy-initialization

I'm building a Spring Data JPA application and securing my API calls using Spring Security.

Principal is loaded through my custom implementation `UserDetailsService.loadByUsername`(...)
, retrieving only the `User` entity itself since all of its associations are LAZY by default.

This is done via a Spring Filter before each controller is hit (I'm doing JWT Auth)

For some requests (say `POST /todo`), however, I will need to load some of the user's lazy associations (the user's Todos) as well in order to add new data to them and persist it.

Is there a suggested practice to achieve that?
My goal is to have some of those associations already loaded (depending on context) when getting the principal through `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` without necessarily setting them to EAGER.

Something along the lines of overriding the
`UserDetailsService.loadByUsername` to JOIN FETCH the associations on demand when I need them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load `@ManyToOne` (like Todos) part of the associations at all.
Just create new `TodoEntity`, assign a user to it and save.

if you need to modify anything, better to work with all the user's associations separately from a user.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with letting these associations just be lazy loaded when requested in code? You can always detach the entity from your entity manager first and then reload it with the fetch joins that you need, based on context. Something like:

```java
User u = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
entityManager.detach(u);
u = entityManager.createQuery("from User u join fetch ... where u.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", u.getId())
    .getResultList()
    .get(0);
// Work with u
```

Comment: I would like to avoid lazy loading associations in code because of the N+1 problem.
Plus, since I set `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to false and I would get a `LazyInitializationException`

Comment: Well, then you will have to do something similar to what I showed with the code, which is detach and re-load the entity with the appropriate fetches.